# (Python) How to rearrange a list based on elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say that I have a list of 3 tuples:

```
[(x, 5), (y, 10), (z, 7)]
```

I'd like to rearrange the listing of the items based on **the 2nd element of each tuple** from largest to smallest so the resulting list can look something like this:

```
[(y, 10), (z, 7), (x,5)]
```

I'm not as fluent in lists than other programming aspects in Python and I find resolving this difficult.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 3):

Just use `.sort` with a key function.

```
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Comment: `key = operator.itemgetter(1)` is faster